# How to update the value of a radio group, when changing another radio group?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

Hi have two radio groups, and i want the values to update when i change one of the radio group value, beause they are both conected.

If i change the first radio group value, i want the second radio group to update.

HTML:

```html
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="cardOrderNumber" (ionChange)="updateCardOrdersNumber($event)">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{'component.loyaltyCard.numberOfOrdersNeeded' | translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>6</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" [value]="6"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>8</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" [value]="8"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>

 <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="updateCardTittle($event)">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{'component.loyaltyCard.cardTitle' | translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Encomende {{cardOrderNumber +1}} pague {{cardOrderNumber}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" value="Encomende {{cardOrderNumber +1}} pague {{cardOrderNumber}}"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Pague {{cardOrderNumber}} receba 1 grátis</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" value="Pague {{cardOrderNumber}} receba 1 grátis"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

ts:

```js
  updateCardOrdersNumber(number1){
    this.cardOrderNumber = number1.detail.value;
    this.cardSquareArray.length = this.cardOrderNumber;
    this.orderRow1.length = this.cardOrderNumber / 2;
    this.orderRow2.length = this.cardOrderNumber / 2;
  }

  updateCardTittle(tittle){
    this.cardTittle = tittle.detail.value;
  }
```

if i change the value of the first radio group, i want the second group value to be updated, because the text of the second group changes when the first radio group value changes.

WHat is the logic that i have to do to update when the first group changes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bind the control using `ngModel` if you are going to handle the `ionChange` event.

Please take a look at **[this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64369438?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

[image: Stackblitz project]

In that demo I'm creating the options of the second group once the user selects an option of the first group, based on the selected option:

### Component:

```
// ...

public selectedOption: number;
  public selectedSuboption: number;

  public options = [
    {
      label: "2 items",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      label: "3 Items",
      value: 3
    }
  ];

  public suboptions = [];

  public updateSelectedOption(event: CustomEvent): void {
    const selectedOption = event.detail.value;

    // Clear existing suboptions
    this.suboptions = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedOption; i++) {
      this.suboptions.push({
        label: `Item ${i + 1}`,
        value: i + 1
      });
    }

    this.selectedOption = selectedOption;
  }

  public updateSelectedSuboption(event: CustomEvent): void {
    this.selectedSuboption = event.detail.value;
  }

// ...
```

### Template:

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="updateSelectedOption($event)">
        <ion-list-header>
          <ion-label>
            Items
          </ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>

        <ion-item *ngFor="let option of options">
          <ion-label>{{ option.label }}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [value]="option.value"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-radio-group>
    </ion-list>

    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedOption">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-radio-group (ionChange)="updateSelectedSuboption($event)">
          <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label>
              Showing {{ selectedOption }} items
            </ion-label>
          </ion-list-header>

          <ion-item *ngFor="let option of suboptions">
            <ion-label>{{ option.label }}</ion-label>
            <ion-radio [value]="option.value"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
    </ng-container>
```