# Update the value of the radio group when changing another radio group?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-group

I have two radio groups.

And the value of the second group, changes when the first group changes. The problem is that the varible value dont change, or i dont get the oportunity to update the value.

First group:

```
<ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="cardOrderNumber" (ionChange)="updateCardOrdersNumber($event)">
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{'component.loyaltyCard.numberOfOrdersNeeded' | translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>6</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" [value]="6"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>8</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" [value]="8"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

this group have two buttons that changes one number

group 2:

```
<ion-radio-group (ionChange)="updateCardTittle($event)"  >
      <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{'component.loyaltyCard.cardTitle' | translate}}</ion-label>
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Encomende {{cardOrderNumber +1}} pague {{cardOrderNumber}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" value="Encomende {{cardOrderNumber +1}} pague {{cardOrderNumber}}"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Pague {{cardOrderNumber}} receba 1 grátis</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" color="success" value="Encomende {{cardOrderNumber}} receba 1 grátis"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

this group have two buttons two, that the value of them changes when the number change of the first group.

The problem is that when the value changes, the value of the radio group dont update. Even with the ionCHange method.

Is there any method that updates the value? Or what can i do to update the value?

The functions on ionCHange are just simple functions that places the value of the radio button into a variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update the value of a radio group, when changing another radio group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369438/how-to-update-the-value-of-a-radio-group-when-changing-another-radio-group)

Answer (score 0):

Each ion-list should have its own ngModel

From the ionic forums:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selection" formControlName="selection">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
      <ion-label>{{fruit}}</ion-label>
      <ion-radio [value]="fruit"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  </div>

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selection = "banana";
    this.form = this._fb.group({
      selection: ["banana"]
    });

    this.fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherimoya"];
  }
```

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-binding-ngmodel-to-radiogroup-for-dynamic-radiobuttons/78645/3